# How to set the port of Chrome when running "flutter run -d chrome" for localStorage?

Tags: flutter

Is there any way to set the port of Chrome when running "flutter run -d chrome"? Without it my localStorage is lost on every run due to the new port/origin.

Or is there another way to keep localStorage across different ports?

Answer (score 20):

I also faced the same problem.
so, I looked for sources related to the flutter run command and found the web options for the command.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/runner/flutter_command.dart#L137

You can set any port using the `--web-port` option.

`flutter run -d chrome --web-port 8080`

Answer (score 11):

you can using any below command to launch flutter web app:

```
flutter run -d chrome --web-port 8080
flutter run -d edge --web-port 8080
flutter run -d web-server --web-port 8080
```

also you can add the additional parameters to the run configuration as this:

```
add `--web-port=8080` to `Additional arguments` in run configuration into toolbar.
```