# How to specify port number in Android Studio for Flutter Web app

Tags: flutter, android-studio

When I start to debug Flutter Web application in Android studio it opens on a arbitrary port ( some time http://localhost:63537/ or http://localhost:54475/ ), each time and so then I have to add that port number as [OAuth 2.0 Client](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=myprojectxyz) . The best could be If port number could be specified in Android studio similar to as shown in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57990398/how-to-set-the-port-of-chrome-when-running-flutter-run-d-chrome-for-localstor) .

Before someone else mark this question as duplicate, it is about Android studio and not command line, so that the break points can be used for debugging.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58248277/how-to-specify-a-port-number-while-running-flutter-web

Answer (score 4):

if running from command line then

flutter run -d web-server --web-port 54475

if running from Android studio then go to Run-> Edit Configuration

[image]

then specify additional run args as required port number

[image: Additional run args]